# Generate response from execute create table/insert in DuckDB

Tags: python, sql, duckdb

I am working on DuckDB through Python, where I do such as:

```
if newtable not in con.sql("SHOW TABLES;").df().name.tolist():
    con.execute("CREATE TABLE newtable AS SELECT * FROM read_csv('my.csv', auto_detect=true)
```

It would be nice to get a response that the table has been created and that x number of rows have been inserted. Ideally:

`Table newtable was created. 201231 rows was inserted`

As an alternative I can do a count(*) query before and after inserts and print it, but it feels a bit hacky if there already is implemented a response. I have tried searching the documentation but I haven't found anything.